# How to best represent a sum over functions that are only defined if the input is contained in another set?

Tags: summation, notation

I have an equation:

$$
S = \sum_{i=1}^k  i - f(i)\cdot \mathbb{1}\left(i \in K\right)
$$

that sums over the difference between an index and a function of that index value. However, the subtraction only occurs if the index is an element in a set $K$. The above formulation doesn't seem like the best representation because the function may not be defined if $i \notin K$. It seems awkward to have to first "compute" $f(i)$ and then kill it off using the indicator function. Is there an alternative formulation that might be more correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are five ways:
$$\sum_{i=1}^k \left(i-f(i)[i\in K]\right) \tag1$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^k \left(i-\begin{cases}f(i)&\text{if $i\in K$}\\0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}\right) \tag2$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^k \left(i-g(i)\right)\tag{3a}$$ where $$g(i)=\begin{cases}f(i)&\text{if $i\in K$}\\0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}\tag{3b}$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^k i-\sum_{i\in\{1,\dots,k\}\cap K} f(i) \tag4$$

$$\frac{k(k+1)}{2}-\sum_{i\in\{1,\dots,k\}\cap K} f(i) \tag5$$

Comment: If I needed to express the equation without separating the sum, such as if we have an absolute value sign: $\sum_{i=1}^k \left|i-f(i)[i\in K]\right|$, is the first equation the best I can do? Thanks!

Comment: I added two other ways that use only one sum each.

Comment: Thank you for this. For the indicator function notation I used originally, is that something mathematicians would consider wrong or perhaps unclear? Or would it be permissible to use normally?

Comment: Your original is clear, but the Iverson bracket $[i\in K]$ or indicator function $1_K(i)$ is probably more common.